# ng-repeat does not work with the list defined in a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and I am trying to learn, I have a table which I try to fill it with an array that I have:

```
<table ng-controller="repeatTest">
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>family name</td>
            <td>score</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.familyName }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.score }}</td>

        </tr>


    </table>
```

and my javascript code is as follow:

```
app.controller('repeatTest', function($scope, sharedService) {
$scope.list = [ {
    name : 'hamed',
    familyName : 'Minaee',
    score : '100'
}, {
    name : 'hamed',
    familyName : 'Minaee',
    score : '100'
} ];
});
```

which works perfectly fine but when I use service to hold he array that I have the table does not render, here is the javascript that I use which does not work:

```
app.service('sharedService', function() {
this.list = [ ];
   });

 app.controller('repeatTest', function($scope, sharedService) {
  sharedService.list = [ {
    name : 'ddd',
    familyName : 'sss',
    score : '100'
}, {
    name : 'www',
    familyName : 'aaa',
    score : '100'
} ];
});
```

Can anyone help me? How can I make my code work with the second approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add it to $scope.  Often times the service is doing an AJAX call.  See this Plunker for a working example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Yx6GYqnSLTzGD2TfB2p8?p=info

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service('sharedService', function() {
    this.list =  [{
      name: 'ddd',
      familyName: 'sss',
     score: '100'
    }, {
      name: 'www',
      familyName: 'aaa',
      score: '100'
   }];
});

app.controller('repeatTest', function($scope, sharedService) {
  $scope.list = sharedService.list ;
});
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="repeatTest">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>family name</td>
      <td>score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.familyName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.score}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

In angular, any values you wish to access in the view layer need to be attached to either the controller as **"this"** or to **"$scope"**.

You set **"sharedService.list"** equal to a value, but that's not available to the view, so **"list"** will be undefined in your `ng-repeat`.

What you'd want to do in your controller is:
`$scope.list = sharedService.list`

and then define your list as:
 `this.list = [...some list here...];`  in your **service**.

Comment: So I assume for these sort of snenarios it does not make sense to make use of service am I right?

Comment: That's pretty much correct, but if you can imagine getting the array you're creating from an AJAX call (using $http), it would actually be very useful.  The method you're using is pretty useful when creating prototypes because you don't have to have a server-side data provider to display a page with data.

Comment: providing mock simulation with plunker or fiddle or codepen or jsbin along with the answer will contribute more to your fine answer. Good answer deserved the upvote. keep it up.

Answer (score 2):

```
 app.service('sharedService', function(){
    this.list = [ {
          name : 'ddd',
          familyName : 'sss',
          score : '100'
            }, {
          name : 'www',
          familyName : 'aaa',
          score : '100'
      } ];
  });

  app.controller('repeatTest', function($scope, sharedService){
    $scope.list = sharedService.list;
  });
```

The simple approach is define data in `service` and use that service in `controller` and bind data using `$scope`.

```
   <table ng-controller="repeatTest">
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>family name</td>
            <td>score</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.familyName }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.score }}</td>

        </tr>

    </table>
```